# How to get TimeZone value in the Java 1.6 through OsloneTimeZone Database

Tags: java, timezone

How to get TimeZone value in the Java 1.6 through OsloneTimeZone Database.

I am passing base64 string of timeZone lyk. "Asia/Kolkata". After that I have to get this Tiezone value in numerical format like + 5.5.

How to do this please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple.  This timezone database is built into java 1.6, however you might need to update your version of tzdata, please check [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html).

So the code then is as follows

```
TimeZone localTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
// next line yields milliseconds
int rawOffset = localTimeZome.getRawOffset();
// next line converts to hours
double hourOffset = (rawOffset / 1000) / 3600.0;
```

If you are happy with a numeric representation (no leading plus if the value is positive) then you are done.  If you want a version with a leading plus, add the following line:

```
String hourOffsetString = (hourOffset > 0.0 ? "+" + hourOffset : "" + hourOffset);
```

Running the full code for me yields +5.5 which I think we both agree is the correct offset for Kolkata.